# Patching a method that is referenced in a constants file, whose constant is pulled into a method under test

Tags: python

I've got a constants file which contains configuration that developers can modify as needed. It's broken apart for readability and so the structure looks something like this:

```
from app.configuration.foo.main import FOO_RULES


MAIN_RULES = {
  'foo': FOO_RULES
}
```

FOO_RULES is defined as:

```
from app.helpers.foo.action_helpers import ActionHelpers

FOO_RULES = {
  'bar': {
     'action_func': ActionHelpers.perform_action,
   },
}
```

I have a separate file/class that imports in `MAIN_RULES` and dynamically parses through the configuration when invoked. When an `action_func` is defined (it *may* be None) it is invoked with a consistent set of arguments. Something to the effect of:

```
from app.configuration.main import MAIN_RULES

class RuleRunner:
  def __init__(self, rule_book):
     self.__rule_book = MAIN_RULES

  def run_rule(self, rule, val_1, val_2):
    rule = self.__rule_book[rule]
    action_func = rule['action_func']

    if action_func is not None:
      action_func(val_1, val_2)
```

The expectation is that we write tests for this configuration since it is a critical portion of our app. What I'm struggling with is I don't want to mock out the configuration  (`MAIN_RULES`) since it lives in the source code and I want to test it all properly (and seems redundant to just do a test for a constants file that isn't just repeating the constant in the file). However, I do want to mock out the call to `ActionHelpers.perform_action` as that is properly unit tested in the test file for action helpers. How do I properly mock out `ActionHelpers.perform_action` without mocking out the entirety of the configuration? Most of the suggestions are only trying to mock out classes/functions directly imported into the file, but this is imported down the chain.

Example test:

```
from app.runners import RuleRunner
import mock

@mock.patch('??????.ActionHelpers.perform_action')
def test_run_role_foo_bar_rule(action_helper_perform_action):
  val_1 = 'fizz'
  val_2 = 'buzz'

  RuleRunner('foo').run_rule('bar', val_1, val_2)

  action_helper_perform_action.assert_called_with(val_1, val_2)
```

Obviously `??????` is likely some module I need to use depending on if this is possible. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Correction to your code

Studying and trying to execute your code I have noted that the `__init__()` method of your class `RuleRunner` contains an error:

```
def __init__(self, rule_book):
    #self.__rule_book = MAIN_RULES   # <---- your code
    self.__rule_book = MAIN_RULES[rule_book]
```

#### The test code with the module `unittest` (not `pytest`)

Now I try to answer to your question:

> How do I properly mock out ActionHelpers.perform_action without mocking out the entirety of the configuration?

A possible test code to achieve your goal is the following (my code starts from your test code):

```
from app.runners import RuleRunner
import unittest
from unittest import mock

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_run_role_foo_bar_rule(self):
        val_1 = 'fizz'
        val_2 = 'buzz'

        action_helper_perform_action = mock.Mock()

        MAIN_RULES_MOCK = {
            'bar': {'action_func': action_helper_perform_action}
        }

        # sut stands for System Under Test
        sut = RuleRunner('foo')

        # assign my MAIN_RULES_MOCK to the attribute of the class RuleRunner
        sut._RuleRunner__rule_book =  MAIN_RULES_MOCK
        sut.run_rule('bar', val_1, val_2)

        action_helper_perform_action.assert_called_with(val_1, val_2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have used the `unittest` module instead of `pytest` (sorry but I don't know `pytest` very well and I don't feel the need to use it).

#### The trick

The only trick to use is to substitute the private attribute `__rule_book` (accessible by `_RuleRunner__rule_book`) with the dictionary `MAIN_RULES_MOCK` which contains a reference to the mock object `action_helper_perform_action` instead a reference to the real function `ActionHelpers.perform_action`.